# Can White Castle? #3

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Since it seems at least some people are enjoying these I'm continuing the series.
This one is not quite as elegant, but still interesting.

**Can White Castle?**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I present to you, pure inefficiency:

> 1. Nf3 f6 2. Nh4 Kf7 3. Nf5 Ke6 4. Nd6 Ke5
>  5. Nc4+ Kf4 6. Nb6 Nh6 7. Nxc8 Ng4 8. Nb6 Nc6
>  9. Nxa8 Nd4 10. Nb6 Nf3+ 11. exf3 Ne5 12. Bd3 Nc4
>  13. Bg6 hxg6 14. Na4 Rh5 15. Nac3 Rh6 16. Qe2 Rh3
>  17. Qe4+ Kg5 18. Qf5+ gxf5 19. Na3 Ne3 20. Ncb5 Kf4
>  21. Nd4 Nc4 22. Nab5 Ne5 23. Na3 Nd3+ 24. cxd3 Ke5
>  25. Nc6+ Kd5 26. Nb4+ Kd4 27. Nd5 Kc5 28. Nc3 Kb4
>  29. Ne4 fxe4 30. Nc2+ Kc5 31. Na3 exd3 32. Nb5 Rh4
>  33. Nc3 Rc4 34. Nd1 Rxc1 35. Rb1 Rc4 36. Rc1 Kb4
>  37. Rc2 Rh4 38. Ne3 Rh3 39. Nd1 dxc2 40. Nc3 Kc4
>  41. Nd1 Kd3 42. Nc3 Rg3 43. Nd5 Rg4 44. Ne3 Rg5
>  45. Nd1 Rg3 46. Ne3 c1=R+ 47. Nd1 Kc2 48. h3 Ra1
>  49. h4 Kc1 50. Nc3 Rh3 51. Ne4 Rh2 52. Nc3 Kc2+
>  53. Nb1 Kd3 54. h5 Kd4 55. h6 Ke5 56. h7 Ke6
>  57. h8=B Kf7 58. d3 Ke8 59. O-O

It can definitely be done faster, but this works.

Comment: Ooo, nice! If correct, that means the answer to the original question is "we can't tell", which is ... disappointing.

Comment: I fried my one brain cell figuring out the trick you see in the answer. What's the "original question"?

Comment: "Can white castle?".

Comment: I understood the question to be, is there a way to reach this position such that white can castle, which this answers

Comment: The question was "Can white castle?". For the avoidance of doubt, there's nothing wrong with your answer -- it makes the answer to that question perfectly clear. I just think there's something ever so slightly _off_ about asking that question when it's not actually answerable. I would hope there was either a proof that W _can_ castle or (much more plausibly, of course) a proof that W _can't_ castle. In this case apparently there's neither.

Comment: Ah, looking back at the first of shoopi's questions of this kind, there it's made explicit that the _real_ question intended is "is it possible that W can castle?".

Comment: There are precious few positions (maybe none) in which a player must be able to castle. I wonder...

Comment: None -- because there's no way to rule out starting the game with Nf3 Nf6; Rg1 Rg8; Rh1 Rh8; Ng1 Ng8 and the same on the Q-side.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan This is "problematic chess" though, which has some rules and conventions that don't apply to regular chess. In particular, since chess problems are traditionally given as board positions without the move history, some conventions are needed to handle the cases where the history is important. Therefore, in all chess problems, capturing en-passant is legal only if it can be explicitly proven so, and [castling is allowed unless it's provably impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrograde_analysis#Castling_and_en_passant_conventions).

Comment: Thanks for explaining Bass. Indeed I dropped the "possibly" since in retrograde it is possible until proven impossible :)

Comment: @Bass Ah, fair enough. Still, the audience here doesn't consist entirely of experienced chess problemists...

Comment: @RShields the only way a player must be able to castle is beither by FEN string (which shows castling rights), or by stipulation. For example, in the following position it is "Mate in 1". By stipulation, white must be able to castle: [here](https://lichess.org/analysis/standard/8/8/5N2/5N2/8/3B1k2/8/4K2R_w_K_-#0)

Comment: A variance of this are positions where one side must have castled in the past, which can be really interesting.

Answer (score 5):

> **Yes!** White can castle in that game.
>
>  ***White had castle variant:*** <kbd>[Apronus PGN Viewer](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nc3_Nc6_Nd5_Ne5_Nb6_Nf3*_exf3_f6_Bd3_Kf7_Bg6*_hxg6_Qe2_Nh6_Qe4_Ng4_Nxc8_Ne5_Nb6_Nd3*_cxd3_Rh5_Qf5_gxf5_Ne2_Rh4_Ng3_Rc4_Ne4_fxe4_Nxa8_exd3_Nb6_Ke6_Nd5_Ke5_Ne3_Kd4_Nd1_Rxc1_h3_Rc4_Rc1_Rc5_Rc2_dxc2_Ne3_Kd3_h4_c1ZR*_Nd1_Ra1_h5_Kc2_h6_Kc1_h7_Rh5_h8ZB_Rh2_O-O_Kc2_Nc3_Kd3_Nb1_Kd4_d3_Ke5_Re1*_Kf5_Re4_Kg6_Kf1_Kf7_Ke1_Rh5_Rh4_Ke8_Rh1_Rh2)</kbd>
>
>     1. Nc3 Nc6 2. Nd5 Ne5 3. Nb6 Nf3+ 4. exf3 f6 5. Bd3 Kf7 6. Bg6+ hxg6 7. Qe2 Nh6 
>     8. Qe4 Ng4 9. Nxc8 Ne5 10. Nb6 Nd3+ 11. cxd3 Rh5 12. Qf5 gxf5 13. Ne2 Rh4 14. 
>     Ng3 Rc4 15. Ne4 fxe4 16. Nxa8 exd3 17. Nb6 Ke6 18. Nd5 Ke5 19. Ne3 Kd4 20. Nd1 
>     Rxc1 21. h3 Rc4 22. Rc1 Rc5 23. Rc2 dxc2 24. Ne3 Kd3 25. h4 c1=R+ 26. Nd1 Ra1 
>     27. h5 Kc2 28. h6 Kc1 29. h7 Rh5 30. h8=B Rh2 31. **O-O** Kc2 32. Nc3 Kd3 33. Nb1 
>     Kd4 34. d3 Ke5 35. Re1+ Kf5 36. Re4 Kg6 37. Kf1 Kf7 38. Ke1 Rh5 39. Rh4 Ke8 40. 
>     Rh1 Rh2 
>
>
>  ***White haven't castle variant:*** <kbd>[Apronus PGN Viewer](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nc3_Nc6_Nd5_Ne5_Nb6_Nf3*_exf3_f6_Nxc8_Kf7_Nb6_Ke6_Nxa8_Nh6_Nb6_Ng4_Bd3_Ne5_Bg6_hxg6_Nd5_Nd3*_cxd3_Ke5_Qe2*_Kd4_Qe4*_Kc5_Qf5_gxf5_Ne2_Rh4_Ng3_Rc4_Ne3_Rxc1*_Nd1_Rc4_Ne4*_fxe4_Ne3_exd3_Nd1_Kd4_Rc1_Rc5_Rc2_dxc2_Ne3_Kd3_Nd1_Rf5_Nc3_c1ZR*_Nd1_Ra1_h3_Kc2_h4_Kc1_Nc3_Rg5_Nb1_Rg3_Nc3_Rh3_Nd1_Rh2_Nc3_Kc2*_Nb1_Kd3_h5_Kd4_h6_Ke5_d3_Ke6_h7_Kf7_h8ZB_Ke8_O-O&n=82)</kbd>
>
>     1. Nc3 Nc6 2. Nd5 Ne5 3. Nb6 Nf3+ 4. exf3 f6 5. Nxc8 Kf7 6. Nb6 Ke6 7. Nxa8 Nh6 
>     8. Nb6 Ng4 9. Bd3 Ne5 10. Bg6 hxg6 11. Nd5 Nd3+ 12. cxd3 Ke5 13. Qe2+ Kd4 14. 
>     Qe4+ Kc5 15. Qf5 gxf5 16. Ne2 Rh4 17. Ng3 Rc4 18. Ne3 Rxc1+ 19. Nd1 Rc4 20. Ne4+ 
>     fxe4 21. Ne3 exd3 22. Nd1 Kd4 23. Rc1 Rc5 24. Rc2 dxc2 25. Ne3 Kd3 26. Nd1 Rf5 
>     27. Nc3 c1=R+ 28. Nd1 Ra1 29. h3 Kc2 30. h4 Kc1 31. Nc3 Rg5 32. Nb1 Rg3 33. Nc3 
>     Rh3 34. Nd1 Rh2 35. Nc3 Kc2+ 36. Nb1 Kd3 37. h5 Kd4 38. h6 Ke5 39. d3 Ke6 40. h7 
>     Kf7 41. h8=B Ke8 42. **O-O**

Comment: The first answer does not seem to be what the question is asking for. The second answer is quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

**Wrong answer** (I made a boneheaded mistake, kindly pointed out in comments by @RShields, to which I have drawn attention below.)

> The WBh8 obviously got there by promotion.
>  The only WP able to reach h8, given the existing WP structure, is the h-pawn.
>  There is no way the BQR can possibly have escaped from behind the pawns.
>  Therefore at least one of the BRs currently on the board is promoted.
>  If it promoted on f1, g1, or h1 then the WK or WR must have moved and W can't castle.
>  If it ever reached d2 then the WK must have moved and W can't castle.
>  If it promoted on d1 then the WK must have moved and W can't castle.
>  So if W can castle, some BP went from c2 to either b1 or c1 and promoted to a R, still on the board.
>  The only available BP is the h-pawn. To get to c2 it must have made 5 captures.
>  W is only missing 6 pieces, so all of them must have been taken by that pawn. <-- **This is the boneheaded mistake**; between writing the previous line and writing this one the number 5 metamorphosed in my brain into the number 6. D'oh!
>  Those captures all have to have been on white squares.
>  But one of W's missing pieces is the WQB (which, note, is *not* the thing now on h8)
>  which can't possibly have been captured on a white square.
>  Hence W cannot castle.

Comment: 5 captures is a little short of 6 pieces :P. Note that W has 6 pawns visible, so one of the missing ones can maybe close the gap.

Comment: We always seem to start out with "no" but then the answer is yes...

Comment: Oh, I miscounted. Oops!

Comment: I mean, when I wrote "6 pieces", I was literally thinking "that matches the 6 captures".